# Multiple drop-downs not working in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Multiple dropdowns are not working for me in bootstrap. Can you tell me what is wrong with it?

Here is my drop down code :

```js
$(function(){ $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){ $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text()); $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text()); }); });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" data-target="#">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" data-target="#">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">LMN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BB</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">EE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">YY</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: $(function(){

      $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

        $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
         $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
      });

    }); This portion I used in javascript. When I select one drop down value. Other drop down value also changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$( ".dropdown-menu li a" ).click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find( ".btn" ).text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" data-target="#">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" data-target="#">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">LMN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BB</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">EE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">YY</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```